# Is the fundamental group of a compact manifold finitely presented?

Tags: fundamental-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $X$ be a connected compact smooth manifold. If $X$ is boundaryless, we can choose a Riemannian metric for $X$ so that $\pi_1(X)$ acts geometrically (ie. properly, cocompactly, isometries) on the universal cover $\tilde{X}$. Because it is know that a group acting geometrically on a simply connected geodesic space is finitely presented (see Bridson and Haefliger's book, *Metric spaces of non-postive curvature*), we deduce that $\pi_1(X)$ is itself finitely presented.

What happens when $X$ has a boundary?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Differentiable manifolds can always be given the structure of [PL manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL_manifold), which can be triangulated into simplicial complexes.  By shrinking a spanning tree of the 1-skeleton of this simplicial complex, we can obtain a [CW complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cw_complex) $X$ with a single $0$-cell. This complex is no longer a manifold, but has the same fundamental group as the original manifold, since quotienting out by a contractible subspace is a homotopy equivalence.

If the manifold is compact, it has a simplicial decomposition with a finite number of cells.  This carries over to $X$.  But the fundamental group of a $CW$ complex with a single $0$-cell has a presentation with a generator for each $1$-cell and a relation for each $2$-cell.  Thus $X$, and therefore the original manifold, has a finitely presented fundamental group.

Answer (score 12):

One can even do a bit better:

Every compact topological manifold (possibly with boundary) is homotopy-equivalent to a finite CW-complex.

That every ANR (absolute neighborhood retract, and every topological manifold with or without boundary is ANR) is homotopy-equivalent to a CW complex,
was known as *Borsuk conjecture.* This conjectire was proven by West in 1974 ([here](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1971155?uid=3737760&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104002130717)) and, later on, a simpler proof was given by Chapman:

*Chapman, T. A.*, [**Invariance of torsion and the Borsuk conjecture**](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1980-103-5), Can. J. Math. 32, 1333-1341 (1980). [ZBL0539.57009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0539.57009).

In the case of topological manifolds it is also a theorem in the (unreadable) book by Kirby and Siebenmann that every compact manifold is homotopy-equivalent to a finite CW-complex.

Comment: by the way: both articles are written by Chapman, perhaps its the wrong link? this seems to be correct article: http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1971155?uid=3737760&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21104002130717 ?

Comment: @Herbert: Yes, wrong link, I will correct it. In any case, I find Chapman's paper to be more readable (still, it uses a lot of heavy machinery).