# Does there exist a smooth compact manifold whose homotopy groups are not finitely generated?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Does there exist a smooth compact manifold whose homotopy groups are not finitely generated?

I found a [counter-example for topological manifolds](https://www.emis.de/journals/GM/vol13nr1/damian/damian.pdf), but I did not understand whether it is possible to introduce a smooth structure on it

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744824/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold-finitely-presented

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the fundamental group of a compact manifold finitely presented?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744824/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold-finitely-presented)

Comment: When you say "$\pi_i(X)$ is finitely generated" do you mean "as a group" or "as a $\pi_1(X)$-module"? Also, when you say "homotopy groups" do you mean "all homotopy groups" or "some homotopy groups"?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I mean finitely generated as groups. I mean, does there exist a compact smooth manifold that does not have the property "all homotopy groups are finitely generated"?

Comment: The links above are only talking about the fundamental group, this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are closed $3$-manifolds with infinite fundamental group, and if $M = M_1 \# M_2$ is the [connected sum](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121571/connected-sum-of-topological-manifolds) of $M_1$ and $M_2$, then the group $\pi_2(M)$ is not finitely generated. The proof uses the fact that $\pi_2(M)$ is isomorphic to $\pi_2(\widetilde M)$, where $\widetilde M$ is the universal covering space of $M$, together with the Hurewicz theorem to deduce $\pi_2(\widetilde M) \approx H_2(\widetilde M)$, together with a get-your-hands-dirty calculation to prove that $H_2(\widetilde M)$ is not finitely generated.

The hypothesis on fundamental groups of $M_1$ and $M_2$ can be considerably weakened, really the only situations to avoid are when one of them is $S^3$ and when both of them are $\mathbb RP^3$.

And, by the way, $M$ has a smooth structure, as does any closed 3-manifold.

Comment: The second homotopy group of every closed 3-manifolds of the form $M_1 \# M_2 $ is not finitely generated with one exception. Fantastic. Thanks a lot.