# Wedge sum of manifolds is homotopy equivalent to manifold?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Is the wedge sum of two $n$-manifolds homotopy equivalent to a manifold?

My guess is yes, at least under some suitable hypotheses.  If they are both smooth, we can embed the wedge sum in some $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $m \geq n$ and find an open subset that deformation retracts onto the embedded space.   I am less optimistic that such a wedge sum is in general homotopy equivalent to a closed manifold.

Is there somely pure algebraic-topological way to make sense of this question?

Comment: Could you clarify: Do you require a closed manifold? The answer will depend on this. Also, are your manifolds topological or smooth? (This does not matter that much in the end.)

Comment: I'm interested in topological manifolds, and a homotopy equivalence to any manifold (not necessarily closed).  However, if there are interesting special cases I would love to hear about those too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every topological manifold is homotopy-equivalent to a finite-dimensional locally-finite simplicial complex.  (This should be in Hatcher's book, see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/201944/topological-n-manifolds-have-the-homotopy-type-of-n-dimensional-cw-complexes) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744824/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold-finitely-presented/745823#745823).) Hence, the wedge sum of topological manifolds is also homotopy-equivalent to a finite-dimensional locally-finite simplicial complex. Lastly, embedding such a complex as a subcomplex in some ${\mathbb R}^N$ and taking an open regular neighborhood of the image yields a smooth open manifold homotopy-equivalent to the above wedge sum.

Of course, if you are insisting on closed manifolds, then the answer is quite different: if $M_1, M_2$ are closed connected $n$-dimensional manifolds ($n\ge 1$), then $H_n(M_1\vee M_2, {\mathbb Z}_2)\cong {\mathbb Z}_2^2$, which implies that  $M_1\vee M_2$ cannot be homotopy-equivalent to a closed connected $n$-dimensional manifold. One sees that disconnected manifolds cannot be homotopy-equivalent to $M_1\vee M_2$ by looking at $H_0$. One similarly rules out closed manifolds of other dimensions.

Comment: Thanks!  Should there be some stipulation around orientability in your second paragraph?

Comment: @orlandpm: Right. I will correct this.