# If $X$ is a manifold and any continuous mapping $f:Y\to X$ is null-homotopic for any compact space $Y$, then is $X$ necessarily contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

From Whitehead's theorem, we can know the statement is correct when $X$ is a CW complex. For general manifold $X$, it seems not clear whether there is a CW structure on $X$. Also, I don't know whether allowing $Y$ to be any compact space, rather than just $S^n$, will help.

Comment: Each manifold is homotopy-equivalent to a CW complex. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744824/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold-finitely-presented/745823#745823).