# Isomorphism between topology of manifolds and graphs

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory

Can all different topologies of manifolds be encoded (isomorphically?) as graphs? How should I formulate this question in google to quickly find answer?

Comment: For topological manifolds it is a difficult issue. But if you have a triangulated manifold, then yes. The graph in question will be the 1-skeleton of the triangulation with those cliques marked which correspond to top-dimensional simplices.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: Can you please give a link to paper which discusses this issue in general case or at least mentions it?

Comment: Do you need a reference to the notion of a triangulated manifold? From that, you would have to work things out yourself, but it is very straightforward.

Comment: No, I want to know about what you wrote "For topological manifolds it is a difficult issue".

Comment: Read Manolescu's paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08163 if you are ready for this staff.

Comment: On the positive side, every manifold is known to be homotopy-equivalent to a simplicial complex (if a manifold if compact, so is the complex). Thus, all homotopy-theoretic information can be encoded in a graph. See the references I gave in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744824/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-compact-manifold-finitely-presented/745823#745823).